# SAP Commerce Cloud Hot Folder local setup

Tags: azure, sap-commerce-cloud, sap-cloud-platform

We are trying to use cloud hot folder functionality and in order to do so we are modifying our existing hot-folder implementation that was not implemented originally for usage within cloud.

Following the steps on this help page:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/0fa6bcf4736c46f78c248512391eb467/SHIP/en-US/4abf9290a64f43b59fbf35a3d8e5ba4d.html

We are trying to test the cloud functionality locally. I have on my machine azurite docker container running and I have modified the mentioned properties in local.properties file but it seems that the files are not being picked up by hybris in any of the cases that we are trying.

First we have in our local azurite storage a blob storage called hybris. Within this blob storage we have folders master>hotfolder, and according to docs uploading a sample.csv file into this should trigger a hot folder upload. 
Also we have a mapping for our hot-folder import that scans the files within this folder: #{baseDirectory}/${tenantId}/sample/classifications. {baseDirectory} is configured using a property like so: ${HYBRIS_DATA_DIR}/sample/import

Can we keep these mappings within our hot folder xml definitions, or do we need to change them?

How should the blob container be named in order for it to be accessible to hybris?

Thank you very much,

I would be very happy to provide any further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did manage to run cloud hot folder imports on local machine.

It was a matter of correctly configuring a number of properties that are used by  cloudhotfolder and azurecloudhotfolder extensions.

Simply use the following properties to set the desired behaviour of the system:

```
cluster.node.groups=integration,yHotfolderCandidate

azure.hotfolder.storage.account.connection-string=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:32770/devstoreaccount1;

azure.hotfolder.storage.container.hotfolder=${tenantId}/your/path/here

cloud.hotfolder.default.mapping.file.name.pattern=^(customer|product|url_media|sampleFilePattern|anotherFileNamePattern)-\\d+.*

cloud.hotfolder.default.images.root.url=http://127.0.0.1:32785/devstoreaccount1/${azure.hotfolder.storage.container.name}/master/path/to/media/folder

cloud.hotfolder.default.mapping.header.catalog=YourProductCatalog
```

And that is it, if there are existing routings for traditional hot folder import, these can also be used but their mappings should be in the value of

```
cloud.hotfolder.default.mapping.file.name.pattern
```

property.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the same - to set up a local dev env to test out the cloud hotfolder.  It seems that you have had some success.  Can you provide where you located the azurecloudhotfolder - which is called out here https://help.sap.com/viewer/0fa6bcf4736c46f78c248512391eb467/SHIP/en-US/4abf9290a64f43b59fbf35a3d8e5ba4d.html

Thanks

Comment: Hi, and sorry for a bit of a late reply. 

http://help.sap.com/disclaimer?site=https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2817992

From this support ticket you can download the whole bundle of hot folder extensions that are needed to run cloud imports on local machine.

Comment: Thanks.  I was successful in doing that as well as making the updates you have suggested.  But still a no go on getting my images.zip file to be processed.  I can see in the azurite container log activity - mostly GET statements but the file never gets processed.  I am on 1811.12.  Any other suggestions - been changing settings in local.properties but no effect at this time. - TIA